# Redis sentinel not switching back to master

Tags: redis-sentinel

here is my setup

```
10.1.0.2 - Master (slave-priority 10)
10.1.0.3 - Slave (slave-priority 100)

10.1.0.2 - Sentinel1
10.1.0.3 - Sentinel2
10.1.0.4 - Sentinel3
```

The failover is working as expected when the Master is down. However, when the original Master already recovered it is not switching back to old Master.